# React / Redux App Issue Fetching Data from MongoDB via API

Tags: reactjs, redux, store, reducers, mern

I am new to Redux and setting up an app with Campaign / Products / Users along with Posts from the [MERN v2.0](http://mern.io/) boilerplate.

I have setup my app to have a fetchPosts action.
My page has the following (code from bottom half)

```
// Actions required to provide data for this component to render in sever side.
PostListPage.need = [() => {
   return fetchPosts();
}];

// Retrieve data from store as props
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    posts: getPosts(state)
  };
}

PostListPage.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PostListPage);
```

Get Posts passes the state and should add posts object to the store.
I can hit the API route and see that the back-end is working and loading the JSON object as expected.

However, my app is giving me an error within the PostReducer --

```
// Get all posts
export const getPosts = state => state.posts.data;
```

The error is when I go to the route --

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
at getPosts (/Users/yasirhossain/Projects/showintel/client/modules/Post/PostReducer.js:31:34)
at mapStateToProps (/Users/yasirhossain/Projects/showintel/client/modules/Post/pages/PostListPage/PostListPage.js:48:12)
at Connect.configureFinalMapState (/Users/yasirhossain/Projects/showintel/node_modules/react-redux/lib/components/connect.js:155:27)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: show us where you [`combineReducers`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html).

Comment: I have a reducers.js file that has the following -- 

import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

// Import Reducers
import app from './modules/App/AppReducer';


// Combine all reducers into one root reducer
export default combineReducers({
  app,
});

Comment: OMG!! epic fail... looks like it didn't add the PostReducer to combine here. this did the trick :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the combineReducer file, I forgot to add PostReducer as alluded to by free_soul in the comments.

```
export default combineReducers({
  app,
  posts,
});
```

Importing PostReducer and adding it, did the trick!